# Reader cannot continue after i've checked for records

Tags: c#, database, null

I have successfully checked that there are values in the database.

Here is the code:

```
if (!reader.Read())
{
    MessageBox.Show(" Can not find user!");
    reader.Close();
}
else
{
    int count = 0;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        string user = (string)reader.GetString(0);
        string name = (string)reader.GetString(1);
        int roll = (int)reader.GetInt32(2);
        string phone = (string)reader.GetString(3);
        string address = (string)reader.GetString(4);
        string birthofdate = (string)reader.GetString(5);
        label1.Text = "" + roll;
        label2.Text = name;
        label3.Text = birthofdate;
        label4.Text = "" + phone;
        label5.Text = address;
    }
}
```

But the problem is that the while loop is skipped anyway.

Comment: did u check the visibility of label???

Comment: Do you really want the cast ?`GetString` will return `string` and `GetInt32` an int

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
if (!reader.Read())
```

with

```
if (!reader.HasRows)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just have the loop so you call `Read` in *one* place, and check `count` afterwards:

```
int count = 0;
while (reader.Read())
{
    ...
}
if (count == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show(" Can not find user!");
}
```

I've removed the `reader.Close()` call - so long as your `reader` is in a `using` statement (which it should be) it'll be closed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use reader.Read() twice, use it only once

```
if (!reader.HasRows)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(" Can not find user!");
                    reader.Close();
                }
                else
                {
                    int count = 0;
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string user = (string)reader.GetString(0);
                        string name = (string)reader.GetString(1);
                        int roll = (int)reader.GetInt32(2);
                        string phone = (string)reader.GetString(3);
                        string address = (string)reader.GetString(4);
                        string birthofdate = (string)reader.GetString(5);
                        label1.Text = "" + roll;
                        label2.Text = name;
                        label3.Text = birthofdate;
                        label4.Text = "" + phone;
                        label5.Text = address;

                    }
                }
```